# default vlfeat sift return less features than sift implementation of D.lowe

Tags: sift, vlfeat

As I mentioned in title default vlfeat sift returns less features than sift of D.Lowe. How could I let vlfeat sift return as much as features as D.Lowe's does. Or can we only offer position info of key-points to extract sift features with vlfeat sift? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under deault settings, vlfeat sift return less features implementation of D.Lowe. The document of vlfeat point out:

*first octave index:*   set to -1 to extract very small features

*number of scale:*         can affect the number of extracted keypoints

*edge threshold:*          decrease to eliminate more keypoints

*peak threshold:*          increase to eliminate more keypoints

So by changing the first octave index and number of scale can increase the number of returned feature.

matlab code example:

```
[f, d] = vl_sift(img, 'levels', 4, 'firstoctave', -1);
```